# Update session within a thread

Tags: multithreading, hibernate

When i try to refresh a session within a thread,its not getting refreshed.After closing the session and reopening the session,objects are refreshed properly.Why is this happening?
Please help me out.

Comment: How are you trying to "refresh" a session?

Comment: And what do you mean by "within a thread"? Java code is always executed within a thread. If youmean that you access a Hibernate session from multiple threads, then you have a big problem: session is not thread-safe at all, and must not be shared between threads.

Comment: You've tagged this questions as multithreading. Hibernate sessions are not thread safe.

Comment: session.refresh(<object>) @jpkrohling

Comment: I am refreshing the session with in run(). How can I over come this if I need to getting database values simultaneously. @JBNizet

Comment: And session.refresh(object) doesn't refreshes the session, it refreshes the specific object within this specific session. Are you saying that refreshing said object doesn't causes the object to be refreshed, ie, reloaded based on the database values?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code sample to make things clearer. Also add your thoughts about wha you want to achieve with the code